# RxSwift. What to use for Observable<Void>?

Tags: swift, mvvm, observable, rx-swift

Writing a project on **MVVM** and trying to bind everything with **RxSwift**.
Unfortunately I did not manage to find a proper way how to bind an actions.

For example, I have a table and a simple cells with one button - "Select".

For this purposes I will have two view models: `ListViewModel` & `CellViewModel`

`ListViewModel` will be creating an array of `CellViewModel` and need to subscribe on selection event(custom event).

Now I'm using BehaviorSubject for this purposes, but it looks ugly. Who can point me how it need to be implemented with **RxSwift**?

```
class CellViewModel {

    private let selectionSubject = BehaviorSubject<Void>(value: ())

    // Will be used by ListViewModel
    var selectionObservable: Observable<Void> {
        return selectionSubject.asObservable()
    }

    func subscribeOnSelection(_ observable: Observable<Void>, disposeBag: DisposeBag) {
        observable
            .bind(to: selectionSubject)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }

    private func autoSelect() {
        selectionSubject.on(next: ())
    }
}

class Cell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet private var selectionButton: UIButton!

    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    func bind(to viewModel: CellViewModel) {
        viewModel.subscribeOnSelection(selectionButton.rx.tap.asObservable(), disposeBag: disposeBag)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a subject somewhere because the emitter of the event doesn't exist when the consumer of the event is created. Normally I put a single subject in the view controller rather than a subject in every cell. Something like this:

```
class Cell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet private var selectionButton: UIButton!

    private var disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    }

    func configure(with makeViewModel: (Observable<Void>, DisposeBag) -> Void) {
        makeViewModel(selectionButton.rx.tap.asObservable(), disposeBag)
    }
}
```

And the view controller would look something like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    var makeViewModel: (Observable<CellID>) -> Observable<[CellID]> = { _ in fatalError() }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let cellSelection = PublishSubject<CellID>()

        let cells = makeViewModel(cellSelection)

        cells
            .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "Cell", cellType: Cell.self)) { index, element, cell in
                cell.configure(with: { selected, disposeBag in
                    selected
                        .map { element }
                        .bind(to: cellSelection)
                        .disposed(by: disposeBag)

                })
                return
            }
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}
```